# How long does a blocked connection from Iptables last? Is there a way to set the timeout?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m recent --set                  # If we receive more than 10 connections in 10 seconds block our friend.
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 5  --hitcount 15 -j Log-N-Drop
```

I have these two relevant rules from iptables. if more than 15 connections are made in 5 seconds it logs the attempt and blocks it. How long does iptables maintain the counter? Does it refresh if connections are attempted again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If more than 15 connections are made in five seconds, their connections are refused until five seconds after the last packet was received.

Comment: It's more like "If there are 15 connections, and the last one was less than 5 seconds ago" according to my interpretation of the docs.  Not all 15 connections would need to have been within the last 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

You can get help on this module by running `iptables -m recent --help`:

The main option related to your question are:

```
[!] --update                    Match if source address in list, also update last-seen time.
```

So my understanding is that with --update it will refresh, but you would need that update prior to the drop.  Therefore if it is first it will 'expire'.  The examples on the [author's page](http://www.snowman.net/projects/ipt_recent/) might help as well. Also the following module parameter comes into play to if more IPs come:

> ip_list_tot=100 ; Number of addresses
>   remembered per table

Edit:
Honestly, thinking about it more I am a bit confused about all the possible scenerios.  I would test this a lot by crafting different source IP addressese with something like scapy for fping. The following module parameter might help as well:

```
debug=0 ; Set to 1 to get lots of debugging info
```

Maybe someone will have a better answer who has experimented with the options, sorry :-/